# How to animate, scale and transforme Views at same time in Android?

Tags: android, animation, transformation, scaling, transition

i want to achieve this and i have read the articles about the Scaling,Translation and animation but i don't how to do this i have tried to create two views and then trying to resize the both view both but in vain.

[image]

here is my View

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context="com.devandro.loginsignup.LandingPage">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loginFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/signUpFrame"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:onClick="viewLogin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30sp"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/signUpFrame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/signUpFrame"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minWidth="80dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="viewSignup"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- Should i have to use Fragments instead of Views?
- How to achieve the translation of text Views LogIn and SignUp?
- How to animation of the Views like this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: View.animate() , Resizing the view by extending the animation class, tried to transform using EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8 but did not succeeded.

Comment: do you know how to make a translate animation and scale animation using an `ObjectAnimator`? if so, whats the problem with the animation that makes both? just call two setters (for translate and scale) at one time

Comment: i have tried to scale and animate at same time but i was unable to calculate the size and apply transition correctly,  secondly it was not giving me a smooth transition that's why i drop the idea to use object animater

Comment: `ObjectAnimator` is ok, just call both `setScaleX` / `setScaleY` and `setTranslationX` / `setTranslationY` in one callback

Comment: @pskink will you please give an example so that i can have an idea, then i will be able to apply same technique on other objects, thanks

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` with `propertyName`  = "foo", then in `void setFoo(float f)` method call the above setters

Comment: Why down vote can any one please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use [Scenes](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html), but it requires Android 4.4.2 (API level 19) or higher. Just change Layout's `weight` property or try to use [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). You need to create 2 layouts (Scenes) and switch between them, and you don't have to handle all animations stuff manually.

Also here's a library for [Android Transitions API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html) backward compatibility: [Transitions Everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere) (if your project's min SDK is lower than 19).